# Insert python string into Django template context with markup

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

If I render a static image in the .html template it works. But if I provide the static markup string as dictionary value to the template (the context), it will not work. It seems to be something to do with string formatting and not allowing me to use {% %} the way I need to. I have tried:
1. .format()
 
2. escaping the percent characters
3. raw strings
4. concatenation
5. autoescape
6. | safe
and a number of other things

Basically, I am constructing a multi-line string in view.py with '''{% %}''', and then rendering a template with this string as the context. Python 2.

**UPDATE**

Simple non-working example:

view.py

```
def index(request):
    image_insert = ''
    images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg']
    for image in images:
        image_insert += '<img src="{}">'.format(image)
    context = {'insert': image_insert}
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic HTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    First Image
    <img src={% static "image.jpg" %}>
    Second Image  <!-- does not work -->
    {{ image_insert | safe }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Page Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic HTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src=/static/mqdefault.jpg>
    Second Image
    <img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, there is a difference. This is Django 1.11 btw if it makes a difference.

Comment: can you please post your template as well?

Comment: @mrehan updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this by passing img source from the view as follow:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

def index(request):
    context = {'image_src': static("image.jpg")}
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic HTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="{{ image_src }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE: Multiple Images**

You can generate markup with multiple images and pass it in the `context` as seen in the `views.py`:

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

def index(request):
    images = [static('image1.jpg'), static('image2.jpg'), static('image3.jpg')]
    images_html = "".join([
        "<img src={image}>".format(image=image)
        for image in images
    ])
    context = {'images_html': images_html)}
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Now, your updated `index.html` will be:
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic HTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ images_html|safe }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the above alternative. Unfortunately, I made a mistake in simplifying my example. I'm actually creating a string via a for loop and then trying to insert that into the template. See updated example. I will +1 you for your time. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @user58446 sure, let me take a look.

Comment: @user58446 I have updated above according to your needs. Don't forget to accept + upvote if this answer your questions. – Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this works now. What exactly did I change? I am creating static objects out of filename strings? Why does this work now?

Comment: @user58446  `"image.jpg"` was invalid static url when you did: `<img src="image.jpg">` – see page source and point out the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

working code:

```
def index(request):
    context = {'image_insert': "image.jpg"}
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic HTML File</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    First Image
    <img src="{% static "image.jpg" %}">
    Second Image  <!-- does not work -->
    <img src="{% static image_insert %}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK. Needed to use the image filename with {% static image %}. I was about two other changes off, but the fact I was getting the default image placeholder led me to believe the problem was elsewhere. OMG. Do you know how long this took from my life? This is obviously the way it is supposed to be done, but none of the examples I read were trying to use the context for insertion. The way I was trying to do it... was it a python string vs. django thing making if fail?

Comment: this happens because the django template backend escape all characters in not safe strings. so when you tray to print the var {{ x }} when x is a code expression ( like your code ) you obtain an escape version of the text (**&quot;image.jpg&quot;**). see the **autoescape** configuration in the default template backend 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django

Comment: OK. I apologize. In simplifying the code to a working example I left out a crucial piece which was causing it to fail (and still is). I updated the above example: I'm actually trying to create a string in a for loop and then insert that into the template. With {{ insert | safe }} I get three placeholder images, and with {% insert %} I get "invalid block tag. did you forget to load or register this tag?". Can this even be done, or do I need to create another nested template for the insert? Sorry for the error.